# How do I create this type of Task List, with columns "Status" and "Description" instead of "Task Status" and "Body"?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have 2 site collections, A and B.

In site collection A, when I create a new Task List, the columns are (I will call it "Type A"):

- % Complete
- Assigned To
- **Body** (this one is different)
- Due Date
- Predecessors
- Priority
- Start Date
- Task Group
- **Task Status** (this one is different)
- Title
- Workflow Name
- Created By
- Modified By

In Site Collection B, the newly created Task List will have columns like this  (I will call it "Type B"):

- % Complete
- Assigned To
- **Description** (this one is different)
- Due Date
- Predecessors
- Priority
- Start Date
- **Status** (this one is different)
- Task Group
- Title
- Workflow Name
- Created By
- Modified By

It seems like these are two types of Task List. I use the same method to create the new task list:

**Site Actions - More Options - (Filter by List) then select "Tasks"**

There are some existing Type B Task List in Site Collection A, but when I create new ones, they are always Type A. How can I create Type B Task List in Site Collection A?

I hope this is not too confusing...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this requirement using your custom [Content Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479905%28v=office.14%29.aspx). you can inherited Task Content Type with your Custom Content Types.and than showing your Requirement field.

Here is showing [Content Type IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543822.aspx) of Task : http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/06/16/sharepoint-2010-base-types-list-template-and-definition-ids-and-content-types-ids/

create your content type from VS2010 like :

```
 <ContentType ID="0x01080100FFbc98c2529347a5886b8d2576b954ef"
               Name="Workflow 1 Tasks 1"
               Group="Workflow 1 Tasks"
               Description="Content Type of Tasks 1 of Workflow 1">
    <FieldRefs>

      <!-- OOTB Task Content Type -->
      <FieldRef ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" />
      <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" Required="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{c3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc6f}" Name="Predecessors" />
      <FieldRef ID="{a8eb573e-9e11-481a-a8c9-1104a54b2fbd}" Name="Priority" />
      <FieldRef ID="{c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76}" Name="Status" />
      <FieldRef ID="{d2311440-1ed6-46ea-b46d-daa643dc3886}" Name="PercentComplete" />
      <FieldRef ID="{53101f38-dd2e-458c-b245-0c236cc13d1a}" Name="AssignedTo" />
      <FieldRef ID="{7662cd2c-f069-4dba-9e35-082cf976e170}" Name="Body" />
      <FieldRef ID="{64cd368d-2f95-4bfc-a1f9-8d4324ecb007}" Name="StartDate" />
      <FieldRef ID="{cd21b4c2-6841-4f9e-a23a-738a65f99889}" Name="DueDate" />
      <FieldRef ID="{58ddda52-c2a3-4650-9178-3bbc1f6e36da}" Name="WorkflowLink" />
      <FieldRef ID="{16b6952f-3ce6-45e0-8f4e-42dac6e12441}" Name="OffsiteParticipant" />
      <FieldRef ID="{4a799ba5-f449-4796-b43e-aa5186c3c414}" Name="OffsiteParticipantReason" />
      <FieldRef ID="{18e1c6fa-ae37-4102-890a-cfb0974ef494}" Name="WorkflowOutcome" />
      <FieldRef ID="{e506d6ca-c2da-4164-b858-306f1c41c9ec}" Name="WorkflowName" />
      <FieldRef ID="{ae069f25-3ac2-4256-b9c3-15dbc15da0e0}" Name="GUID" />
      <FieldRef ID="{8d96aa48-9dff-46cf-8538-84c747ffa877}" Name="TaskType" />
      <FieldRef ID="{17ca3a22-fdfe-46eb-99b5-9646baed3f16}" Name="FormURN" />
      <FieldRef ID="{78eae64a-f5f2-49af-b416-3247b76f46a1}" Name="FormData" />
      <FieldRef ID="{8cbb9252-1035-4156-9c35-f54e9056c65a}" Name="EmailBody" />
      <FieldRef ID="{47f68c3b-8930-406f-bde2-4a8c669ee87c}" Name="HasCustomEmailBody" />
      <FieldRef ID="{cb2413f2-7de9-4afc-8587-1ca3f563f624}" Name="SendEmailNotification" />
      <FieldRef ID="{4d2444c2-0e97-476c-a2a3-e9e4a9c73009}" Name="PendingModTime" />
      <FieldRef ID="{35363960-d998-4aad-b7e8-058dfe2c669e}" Name="Completed" />
      <FieldRef ID="{1bfee788-69b7-4765-b109-d4d9c31d1ac1}" Name="WorkflowListId" />
      <FieldRef ID="{8e234c69-02b0-42d9-8046-d5f49bf0174f}" Name="WorkflowItemId" />
      <FieldRef ID="{1c5518e2-1e99-49fe-bfc6-1a8de3ba16e2}" Name="ExtendedProperties" />
     <!-- OOTB Task Content Type -->

     <!-- Add your additional colums what you want. -->


    </FieldRefs>

    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>ListForm</Display>
          <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
          <New>ListForm</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
```

> after create two custom content types. content Type A and content Type B and set it to Default when its required on your list.

Hops its helps!!!

Comment: Curious, will this also apply in SP2013?